# monkey-patching python an instance method

Tags: python

I'm trying to monkey-patch a class instance, but don't quite see how I can patch a class method no problem.

```
>>> class Simple(object): 
...     def make(self, arg):
...         return arg * 2
... 
>>> s = Simple()
>>> def times_four(self, arg):
...   return arg * 4
... 
>>> Simple.make = times_four
>>> s.make(10)
40
```

But say I only wanted to replace `make` in the instance, what's the easiest way to do that?

```
>>> def times_eight(self, arg):
...   return arg * 8
>>> s.make = ???
```

Comment: possibly...  I don't really understand what's going on in that code.

Comment: is my question "mocking" or "monkey-patching"?

Comment: Can you explain the difference, please?

Comment: Technically these terms are somewhat synonymous. The difference is in intentions - mocking is usually monkey-patching for the purpose of testing, whereas the latter, in its origins is more general.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create a new instance method out of `times_eight` by using its [`__get__` special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__):

```
>>> class Simple(object):
...     def make(self, arg):
...         return arg * 2
...
>>> s = Simple()
>>> def times_eight(self, arg):
...     return arg * 8
...
>>> s.make = times_eight.__get__(s, Simple)
>>> s.make(10)
80
>>> type(s.make)
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>>
```

Comment: Your solution also works well.  I was just showing how to do it without importing `types.MethodType`. :)

Comment: Does using `super()` inside `times_eight()` work?

Comment: short: `s.make = times_eight.__get__(s)`

Answer (score 10):

Doh!

```
>>> import types
>>> s.make = types.MethodType(times_eight, s, Simple)
>>> s.make(10)
80
```

Answer (score 7):

Methods only get the `self` arg passed automatically when received from the class (not from the instance dict), so you'll need to pass an 1-arg function there:

```
s.make = lambda arg: times_eight(s, arg)
```

(You can simplify that with `functools.partial`.)

Comment: I think better to add object to closure `lambda arg, s=s: time_eight(s, arg)`

Comment: This isn't really making an instance method, however. Right?  It's a lambda or a partial, so I don't think this really works.

Comment: that lambda trick is a very clear way to monkey patch an instance, rather than the class. Bravo!