# Override a method of an attribute

Tags: python

I have a class that has an attribute as an object from another class. A third class inherits from the first class, and in there, I want to override the attribute's method ...

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, door):
        self.door = door

class Door:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def change_color(self):
        pass

class CarConstruct(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CarConstruct, self).__init__(Door('red'))
        # Here, I want to override self.door.change_color method
```

What is the best way to override in such a situation?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with thism

Comment: You can't override other objects' methods.

Comment: @klausD. A problem in a GUI. The GUI uses a template where its ´self.content´ is class that has a ´FigureCanvasQTAgg´ in it, which is connected to a mouse event. In the main GUI class, I want to override (define) this mouse clicking event

Comment: The proper way to override a method is with a subclass. Define a subclass of `Door` with the appropriate method, and pass an instance of *that* class to `super().__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called ["monkey patching"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching). In general it should be avoided, because it makes the code very hard to understand and reason about. Avoid it unless you have a very good cause. One of the good causes might be to [mock a method in unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

If you still want to monkey patch just one method on one object `self.door` - [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127874/monkey-patching-python-an-instance-method).

Comment: If you have found a monkey patch in one of two thousand tests at a place totally unrelated to the problem you where debugging and after three day of head scratching, then you know how "good" your case is.

Comment: lol. That's the price you have to pay for using a dynamic programming language :)

Comment: …without some discipline. ;-)