Using animated QIcon in QMessageBox in PyQt5?
I want an animated icon for my QMessageBox - and I found QtAwesome has a nice animated spinner.
So I tried this very simple example:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
import qtawesome as qta

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
    self.setWindowTitle('Hello World')
    self.show()
    msgBox = QMessageBox( QMessageBox.NoIcon, "Title", "Content ...", QMessageBox.Cancel )
    animation = qta.Spin(msgBox)
    spin_icon = qta.icon('fa5s.spinner', color='red', animation=animation)
    msgBox.setIcon(spin_icon)
    returnValue = msgBox.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

... however, unfortunately it crashes with:
$ python3 my_qttest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/my_qttest.py", line 23, in <module>
    ex = Example()
         ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/my_qttest.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:/msys64/tmp/my_qttest.py", line 18, in initUI
    msgBox.setIcon(spin_icon)
TypeError: setIcon(self, a0: QMessageBox.Icon): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QIcon'

Hmm, I kinda thought .setIcon would accept a QIcon object, but actually it does not - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html notes that QMessageBox::Icon is actually an enum (not a class, as I thought at first):
Constant                Value   Description
QMessageBox::NoIcon     0       the message box does not have any icon.
QMessageBox::Question   4       an icon indicating that the message is asking a question.
...

... however, qta.icon gives back a QIcon.
So, how could I use an animated QIcon for the QMessageBox?

Try with: msgBox.setIconPixmap(icon.pixmap())

Thanks to the comment by @eyllanesc :

Try with: msgBox.setIconPixmap(icon.pixmap())

... i finally got it working:

... although it is not as trivial as the comment implies so I'll post the details in this answer:

Retrieving the pixmap with .pixmap() method actually requires a size - so we'd want to use the pixmap size that is originally used in the QMessageBox
Note that if we use QMessageBox.NoIcon as in the OP, we will read a pixmap size of 0,0 which is unusable - so we will have to initialize with some of the other normal QMessageBox icons so we can retrieve their original pixmap size
Even when we manage to setIconPixmap, only a single image will be shown, not an animation - to get the animation working, we'll have to monkeypatch the QtAwesome Spin instance's _update method, and do a setIconPixmap from there

In all, the code is now this:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QRect
import qtawesome as qta

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
    self.setWindowTitle('Hello World')
    self.show()
    msgBox = QMessageBox( QMessageBox.Information, "Title", "Content ...", QMessageBox.Cancel )
    msg_newpos_geom = QRect(QPoint(350,350), msgBox.sizeHint())
    msgBox.move(msg_newpos_geom.topLeft())
    orig_ipmsize = msgBox.iconPixmap().size()
    print(orig_ipmsize.width(), orig_ipmsize.height()) # 0 0 for QMessageBox.NoIcon; 32 32 for QMessageBox.Information
    animation = qta.Spin(msgBox, autostart=True)
    spin_icon = qta.icon('fa5s.spinner', color='red', animation=animation)
    # msgBox.setIconPixmap(spin_icon.pixmap(orig_ipmsize)) #msgBox.setIcon(spin_icon) # if this statement is enabled/running here, it prevents new_anim_update from running!

    # this is DO_MONKEYPATCH = 1 approach from https://stackoverflow.com/q/78325356 :
    old_anim_update = animation._update
    def new_anim_update(self):
      old_anim_update() # no error
      #print("new_anim_update {}".format(self)) # self is <qtawesome.animation.Spin object at 0x00000238f1d45f10>
      msgBox.setIconPixmap(spin_icon.pixmap(orig_ipmsize))
    animation._update = new_anim_update.__get__(animation, qta.Spin) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127947

    #print(animation._update)
    msgBox.setIconPixmap(spin_icon.pixmap(orig_ipmsize)) #msgBox.setIcon(spin_icon)
    #animation.start()
    returnValue = msgBox.exec()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

